# Horizontal scrollbar appears sometimes

Tags: html, css, overflow, image-resizing, horizontal-scrolling

- I want to remove the horizontal scrollbar from my webpage. For which
  i use overflow-x property
  and pseoudo element property webkit-scrollbar in which I write display none.But the problem
  still exists sometimes when I shrink my webpage. Like if I write the property over-flow-x:
  hidden then on first time shrinking the screen , the horizontal scrollbar doesnot
  show but on 2nd time shrinking screen it appears. This is the issue which I am facing. Please give me an appropiate solution as soon as possible.
  Thanks.

Comment: Could you prevent some code so we can help you more easily ?

Comment: you can use overflow-x: hidden; property in body css

Answer (score 0):

Use this to hide scrollbar and preserve functionality:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;=
}
```

Add this along to remove scroll functionality:

```
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: wont this hide vertical scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```css
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overflow {
  width: 150vw;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'overflow'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed ipsum in sapien sagittis pulvinar. Cras ornare massa urna, in volutpat quam feugiat sit amet. Sed in purus efficitur justo vestibulum scelerisque. Integer euismod ligula a nisl ornare, vel viverra mi mattis. Mauris dolor diam, tempus a risus in, malesuada fringilla tellus. Vivamus ultrices nisi non massa ultrices mollis at vitae neque. Vivamus viverra fringilla elit, eu suscipit libero dictum nec. Quisque lacinia mattis rutrum.
Aliquam ut dignissim magna. In eget maximus libero. Donec id velit vitae libero ultricies consectetur. Duis in tortor mattis, venenatis elit sit amet, iaculis ligula. Sed pulvinar nisi ut leo sollicitudin tempor. Ut nec erat sed nisl blandit efficitur. Donec varius sem vitae leo tincidunt, sed pretium tortor tempus. Morbi tempor sollicitudin sapien eget sollicitudin. Fusce maximus quis risus ac pretium. Duis non elit nec neque consectetur interdum vitae at lorem. Proin elementum sem justo, non congue orci cursus in. Nulla ac feugiat augue. Cras augue lorem, pretium non velit non, pulvinar accumsan dui.
</div>
```

If this doesn't work then you will have to post your code for us to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

have you set margin for that? besides your given code is perfect. If you want to remove the scroll bar than view width should be according to the display or to give a width you can use max-width : 100%